# If $A \subset B$ OR $B⊆A$ Then $\mathcal P (A∪B) = \mathcal P (A) ∪ \mathcal P (B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

I start to solve it by proof both sides to proof the equals.

First:
Let $S\in P[A]\cup P[B]$.
Then either $S\subset A$ or $S \subset B$.
Then
$$S\subset A\implies S\subset A\cup B \implies S\in P[A\cup B]  $$
$$S\subset B\implies S\subset A\cup B \implies S\in P[A\cup B]  $$
So: $$S\in P[A\cup B]$$

I can't proof the other side of:
$P[A\cup B] ⟹ P[A]\cup P[B]$

Comment: Hint. If $A$ is a subset of $B$ then $A \cup B = B$. How is the power set of $A$ related to the power set of $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B\subset A$, then if $S\in P(A\cup B)$ you get $S \subset A$ or $S \subset B \subset A$. Therefore $S\subset A$ and thus $S\in P(A)\subset P(A)\cup P(B)$.

Similarily if $B\subset A$ you have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

It is true for any pair of sets $A$ and $B$ that $P(A)\cup P(B)\subseteq P(A\cup B)$.

Indeed, if $X\subseteq Y$, then clearly $P(X)\subseteq P(Y)$, because any subset of $X$ is also a subset of $Y$.

Hence $P(A)\subseteq P(A\cup B)$ and $P(B)\subseteq P(A\cup B)$, whence the thesis.

For proving the reverse inclusion under the assumption that either $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$, observe that, if $A\subseteq B$, we have $A\cup B=B$, so $P(A\cup B)=P(B)$; since $P(A)\subseteq P(B)$, we clearly have $P(A\cup B)=P(A)\cup P(B)$. Similarly in the other case.

Actually, you can prove that

> if $P(A\cup B)=P(A)\cup P(B)$, then either $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$.

Indeed, if $P(A\cup B)=P(A)\cup P(B)$, then either $A\cup B\in P(A)$ or $A\cup B\in P(B)$. In the first case $A\cup B\subseteq A$, which is equivalent to $B\subseteq A$. Similarly in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

If $A \subseteq B$ then $\cal{P}$$(A \cup B)=\cal{P}$$(B)$ because $A\cup B=B.$ $(1)$

If $B \subseteq A$ then $\cal{P}$$(A \cup B)=\cal{P}$$(A)$ because $A\cup B=A.$ $(2)$

$(1), (2) \Rightarrow $ If $A \subseteq B$ **or** $B \subseteq A$ then $\cal{P}$$(A \cup B)=\cal{P}$$(B)$ **or** $\cal{P}$$(A \cup B)=\cal{P}$$(A)$.

$\Rightarrow $ If $A \subseteq B$ **or** $B \subseteq A$ then $\cal{P}$$(A \cup B)=\cal{P}$$(B)$ **or** $\cal{P}$$(A)$.

$\Rightarrow $ If $A \subseteq B$ **or** $B \subseteq A$ then $\cal{P}$$(A \cup B)=\cal{P}$$(B) \cup \cal{P}$$(A)$.